when I want to logout it shows HTTP ERROR 405
please help me. I'm trying to make a logout, but it only give HTTP ERROR 405.
I read some info about this problem, that it gives "GET" method and I need a "POST" method, but it still doesn't work.
urls.py
enter image description here
logged_out.html
enter image description here
Tried to log out but it doesn't work

not "users:logout", just "logout"

Will be better if you will redefine login, logout paths in urlpatterns, using LoginView and LogoutView
